# Installing, Configuring, and Testing WebLogic Server 12c Developer Zip Distribution in NetBeans

Tags: cmd, weblogic, weblogic12c

I'm trying to install weblogic server in my Netbeans IDE but I'm unable to run this command "configure.cmd". This is the error I'm getting:

'configure.cmd' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Here's the link I'm following to install the weblogic server: [Oracle Weblogic Server installation](https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/wls_12c_netbeans_install/wls_12c_netbeans_install.html)

Thanks!

Comment: Are you in the "MW_HOME(D:\weblogic\wls)" directory? Is the configure.cmd file in the directory?

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I don't have the configure.cmd file in the directory.

Comment: Then, this sounds like an installation issue. Where did you install the server? What is your `MW_HOME` directory?

Comment: If the installation is correct then the config.cmd file should be in the following location. <MiddlewareHome>\<server version>\oracle_common\common\bin. Once you run the config and create a domain then you register the server with NetBeans using the newly created domain.

Comment: Thank you Chad, Now it's working fine....I'm able to run the command.